# Convert epoch time to human readable timestamp in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table column name start_time with epoch time data. I need to query that table and display it as human readable datetime something like 01/11/2023 09:05:23. I tried TO_DATE function and also TO_TIMESTAMP function as well in multiple ways but nothing worked for me. Help me with the function to use.
Thank you